# How to count no of text boxes present inside a div using PHP

Tags: php, html

I need one help.I have multiple text field inside a div and i need to count those using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
  <div class="questionshowp">
        <input name="optional_0_0_ans" id="optional_0_0_ans" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
     <input name="optional_0_1_ans" id="optional_0_1_ans" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
     <input name="optional_0_2_ans" id="optional_0_2_ans" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
    </div>
<?php

?>
```

Here 3 input fields are present inside a div.Here i need to echo how many nos of field is present using PHP.Please help me.

Comment: How the input fields are rendered? any loop?

Comment: PHP is a server side.  You sure you don't mean you want JavaScript on the client to count them?

Comment: What is the purpose ? You can count the `input` using JavaScript easily.

Comment: @subhra if they are rendered within loop, count would be the max limit of the loop.

Comment: @Alok ,Yes thats true

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the HTML is not built/rendered using PHP, so then you can use the PHP built-in DOM parser.

```php
<?php
//** Load the HTML **//
//$html  = file_get_contents('http://www.url.com'); //Load the HTML from external webpage.
$html  = file_get_contents(__FILE__); //Load the HTML from the current webpage.

//** Load HTML contents into DOM tree **//
$dom   = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

//** Initialize DOM Parser **//
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

//** Parse DOM for all occurences of <input> with parent <div> with class ="questionshowp' **//
$inputs = $finder->query("/html/body/div[@class='questionshowp']/input");

//** Determine how many input fields have type='text' **//
$count = 0;
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
  if ($input->getAttribute('type') === 'text') {
   $count++;
  }
}

//** Print Results! **//
echo "Number of <input> fields where @type = 'text' is -> " .$count ."\n";
```

**REFERENCE** 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag $count and increment inside the for loop

```
$count = 0;

for loop {
$count++
}
echo $count;
```

or

$count = count($listValue);